# mysql counterpart of php's in_array

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM conversations WHERE chatMembers LIKE '%1%'AND chatMembers LIKE '%10%'
```

**conversations table**

```
id | chatMembers | conversation
1  |  1^10       | .......
2  |  1^100      | .......
3  |  10^100     | .......
```

The column chatMembers contains userIds involved in that conversation.
I want to select only the row with userIds 1 and 10 from conversations table, but the query above returns all the rows, even the rows containing 10 and 100, etc.

Im thinking of a way that works the same as php's in_array but for strings.

Comment: What string will be stored in chatmembers field ?

Comment: chatMembers field will be filled by userIds separated by "^" as delimiter

Comment: Please give example chatmembers value

Comment: please read my question. I have provided the conversations table with sample values

Comment: Although this would require refactoring, I suggest building a proper many-to-many relationship, i.e. have a "pivot table" called `conversations_users` with columns `conversation_id` and `user_id`, then query the table with JOINs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `%` on both sides it means that you are selecting any row which contains both 1 and 10 in the string. So 100 also contains 1 and 10 (in string format) and so is selected.

```
SELECT * FROM conversations WHERE ( 
 chatMembers LIKE '%^1^%' 
   OR 
 chatMembers LIKE  '%^1' 
  OR 
 chatMembers LIKE  '1^%' )
 AND(
  chatMembers LIKE '%^10^%' 
   OR 
 chatMembers LIKE  '%^10' 
  OR 
 chatMembers LIKE  '10^%' )
```

Comment: I see maandoo had covered all possible criteria. However, if chatMembers only has two members (separated by "^") for each row, the '%^1^%' and '%^10^%' can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this,

```
SELECT * FROM conversations WHERE (chatMembers LIKE '%1^%' or chatMembers LIKE '%^1%' or chatMembers LIKE '%^1^%')AND (chatMembers LIKE '%10^%' or chatMembers LIKE '%^10%' or chatMembers LIKE '%^10^%')
```